# Firebase Auth - Unable to Add Phone Number for Testing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm unable to add a phone number for testing my Firebase Phone Authentication workflow. See the images below:

Firebase Phone Auth Panel
[image: Firebase Phone Auth]

After providing a valid phone number/verification code and clicking "Add", I get this error:
[image]

I've tried to register my device multiple times over the last two weeks with the same outcome.  Hopefully someone has seen this before and if so, is there a solution?

UPDATE:

I've tried the following number formats with the same results -

+1 123-456-7890

+11234567890

Comment: Please post how you entered the phone number

Comment: @JustinFrazer - Please use fictitious phone numbers to avoid affecting user accounts.

Comment: real phone number gives that error

Comment: @AmodGokhale Please advise on what's a more fictitious phone number than counting from 1-10?

Comment: If you're having problems working with the Firebase console, contact Firebase support directly for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @AmodGokhale it won't give error i tried mine and worked properly

Comment: It also might be worth noting that I had the same test number working on a prior project, not sure what's going on.

Comment: @JustinFrazer if you look at info button at top . it does recommend to use fictional phone numbers. I just tried this number +213 121313131 and it accepted it... but for real number i got same message as yours. May be because the number i tried is in actual users list. Like mentioned above by Doug, please contact support team. I think the message is wrong. If number you are trying is in actual users list its rejecting it??? ( its just my guess )

Comment: As suggested, i've reached out to Firebase Support. Will add details when they're available

Comment: @AmodGokhale I was in fact using a 'real' phone number which resulted in the thrown error. After using a more 'fictitious' number, it was successful (i.e +1 111-111-1111). Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, I was using my personal phone number as the number for test; which I successfully used on a previous Firebase-backed project with the same feature. I removed the test phone number from the Firebase project as I had finished testing the feature. I think it very well may be a bug on Firebase's end

I was successfully able to use the phone number "+1 111-111-1111"

UPDATE:

After successfully using the '+1 111-111-1111' phone number, deleting it, and trying to re-enter it, I was greeted with the same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the User phoneNumber in the authentication tab before you can add (or re-add) a phone number as a test phone number

Answer (score 1):

1. First delete number for Authentication > User Tab.
2. Then add number now, it works perfectly.